# The purpose of enable attribute of Spring Security User class

Tags: spring, spring-security

What is the purpose of `enable` attribute of `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` class? Should I always keep that attribute in my 'user' table and use it to populate User instances when being fetched?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See [UserDetails](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html#isEnabled--) interface for more details and check `isEnabled()` method.

> Indicates whether the user is enabled or disabled. A disabled user cannot be authenticated.

The attribute is used when a user is being authenticated. If the user is disabled, Spring Security throws `DisabledException` exception.

However, you can implement your own `AuthenticationProvider` that will ignore this attribute if it is useless for you or you can set it always to **true** when `User` instances are being created.

Hence, whether to keep this attribute in a persistent storage depends only on your needs.